# When Android compose BackdropScaffold is open the user cannot scroll the frontcontent list down to display last item completely

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose-scaffold

i have a main screen in my android app that is employing `androidx.compose.material.BackdropScaffold`
the `frontcontent` hosts a list of items
it all works fine, however when the `backdrop` is "open" the `frontcontent` list
cannot be scrolled down far enough to display the entire content of the last list item
is there a `BackdropScaffold`
configuration i am missing to allow the `backdrop` to be open and the user can scroll down to see the complete
last item?

backdrop doesnt have `sheetPeekHeight`

```
@Composable
@ExperimentalMaterialApi
fun BackdropScaffold(
    appBar: @Composable () -> Unit,
    backLayerContent: @Composable () -> Unit,
    frontLayerContent: @Composable () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    scaffoldState: BackdropScaffoldState = rememberBackdropScaffoldState(Concealed),
    gesturesEnabled: Boolean = true,
    peekHeight: Dp = BackdropScaffoldDefaults.PeekHeight,
    headerHeight: Dp = BackdropScaffoldDefaults.HeaderHeight,
    persistentAppBar: Boolean = true,
    stickyFrontLayer: Boolean = true,
    backLayerBackgroundColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colors.primary,
    backLayerContentColor: Color = contentColorFor(backLayerBackgroundColor),
    frontLayerShape: Shape = BackdropScaffoldDefaults.frontLayerShape,
    frontLayerElevation: Dp = BackdropScaffoldDefaults.FrontLayerElevation,
    frontLayerBackgroundColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colors.surface,
    frontLayerContentColor: Color = contentColorFor(frontLayerBackgroundColor),
    frontLayerScrimColor: Color = BackdropScaffoldDefaults.frontLayerScrimColor,
    snackbarHost: @Composable (SnackbarHostState) -> Unit = { SnackbarHost(it) }
) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for?

```
BottomSheetScaffold(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(0.dp),
        scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
        //change this height
        sheetPeekHeight = 77.dp,
.
.
.
    sheetContent = {
        ...
    }) {
      ...
    }
```